# SharePoint + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail" + not working for specific account

Tags: email, authorization, sputility, spgroup

Ours is a SharePoint 2016 On Prem env.
We have developed a custom component which uses

> "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail"

to send email. Email is getting sent. Except for a specific account.
All the accounts including one not receiving email is in same domain (i.e. no external user).

Note: the page on which the email sending js file is referenced has restricted access. That is access is limited to set of users belonging to a AD group. This AD group doesn't include the failing user account.

**However, i am not able to figure-out what page permissions has to do to sending email.**

Trying for solution following a link, added User having issue to a SharePoint group. There after able to send email to the said account.

**Is it compulsory for an account to be part of SharePoint group to receive emails?**